# array set as a column name from an array using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, foreach

I have an foreach loop that is creating a table with new column names from an array collected from a site. At the moment only the first element of the array is being set as a column name, can someone help?

H
Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
include 'connection.php';

function getsquad($url, $tablename){

$html = file_get_html($url);

$player_fromsite = array();

$space = ' ';
$replacespace = '_';

$player = array();

foreach($html->find('td[align=left]') as $element) {
   if ($element->children(0)) { // work only when children exists
          array_push($player_fromsite ,$element->children(0)->innertext);
   }
}

//$player[] = str_replace($space, $replacespace, $player_fromsite);
//unset($player_fromsite);

$length = count($player);

foreach($player_fromsite as $player_name) {
  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE " . $tablename . "(" . str_replace($space, $replacespace,     $player_name) . " VARCHAR(30))") or die(mysql_error());   
}

echo "Table Created!";

}

$Squad = new squad();
$Squad->getsquad('site', 'Ars');

?>
```

any spaces are replace with a "_", in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I correctly understand what you want: In `$player_fromsite` you have some strings, which should become columns of the new table with the name from `$tablename`, whereas all columns are `VARCHAR(30)`.

If so, replace your last foreach loop with the following:

```
$columns = array();
foreach ($player_fromsite as $player_name) {
    $columns[] = '`' . str_replace($space, $resplacespace, $player_name) . '` VARCHAR(30)';
}
$query = 'CREATE TABLE `' . $tablename . '` (' . implode(',', $columns) . ')';
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

The foreach loop basically prepares all the columns, which afterwards get concatenated to the actual query which is send to the database.

So for exmaple let `$player_fromsite = array('foo', 'bar')`, you would end up with the query

```
CREATE TABLE `Ars` (`foo` VARCHAR(30),`bar` VARCHAR(30));
```

Comment: I have an error message saying "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  '–zil VARCHAR(30),Bacary_Sagna VARCHAR(30),Jack_Wilshere VARCHAR(30),Santi_Cazo' at line 1" these are the players names I'm trying to make into columns. It's the closest so far

Comment: I edited my answer and added some backticks to the query for table and column names, can you try it again?

Comment: Wow, this worked. I been working on this for couple of day and so many people say it wasn't possible but here the answer. Thanks for the code

Comment: What does the backticks dO?

Comment: With backtics it is possible to have some characters in a table or column name, which normally are forbidden as of syntax restrictions. So for example where `SELECT * FROM -foo` is a syntax error, adding backticks around the table name makes it a wellfromed query. See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html